# Xcode Bitcode issue when archiving

Tags: xcode, bitcode

I have pod in my project called `GoogleWebRTC` and apparently it is not build `Bitcode` enabled.

Though I do disable `Bitcode` for it in my `Podfile` which can be seen below, it does not let me to archive the project. Only thing that works is to disable `Bitcode` in my main project and target.

```
#bitcode enable
post_install do |installer|
  
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
  
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      
      # set valid architecture
      config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS'] = 'arm64 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64'
      
      # build active architecture only (Debug build all)
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
      
      if target.name == "GoogleWebRTC"
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
        else
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
        if config.name == 'Release' || config.name == 'Release (Preprod)'
          config.build_settings['BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE'] = 'bitcode'
          else # Debug
          config.build_settings['BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE'] = 'marker'
        end
        
        cflags = config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'] || ['$(inherited)']
        
        if config.name == 'Release' || config.name == 'Release (Preprod)'
          cflags << '-fembed-bitcode'
          else # Debug
          cflags << '-fembed-bitcode-marker'
        end
        
        config.build_settings['OTHER_CFLAGS'] = cflags
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is not occuring when I run or build it in Debug, but in Release it is not working and throws

`'/Users/**/Projects/**/Pods/GoogleWebRTC/Frameworks/frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/**/Projects/**/Pods/GoogleWebRTC/Frameworks/frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC' for architecture arm64`

I do not know how beneficial of having `Bitcode` enabled for a project but as far I get it is that initially for a project it is enabled. I tried some much variations in both project and pod build settings but only thing that works is disabling `Bitcode` for the main project and target.

I have found some answers on another topics talking about building the library manually with bitcode enabled but all the links referenced are broken. Maybe there is an alternative pod already which already built bitcode enabled. I am open to any kind of suggestion, other than removing `GoogleWebRTC`.

Comment: "Only thing that works is to disable Bitcode" So what's the problem? Just do that.

Comment: Well, I did that. But I dont know what enabling bitcode actually affects and I am a bit worried that disabling it will have some kind of consequences in the future.

Comment: Well, then find out what Bitcode is, so you can make an informed decision. Personally I never turn Bitcode on and I think it's worse than silly, but that's just an opinion.